# Receiving actions from custom tableviewcell

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a custom tableViewCell which has 3 actions associated with it.

Where do I handle these actions and handle the row on which they are taking place?

For example, if button2 is pressed on table row 3, how is this handled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is a conditional for where you want to place your buttons and then add the targets and selectors to those buttons.

For example

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
//Do your conditionals like this
if(indexPath.row == 2){
[cell.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
//another row another method
else if(indexPath.row == 4){
[cell.yourOtherButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourOtherMethod:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, although I'm not sure you've completely understood the question..? Basically, I have a prototype cell with 3 buttons on it. Say I have 10 items in an array, and so this prototype cell appears 10 times in my table view, when I tap one of the 3 buttons on any cell, how do I call an action from it and how do I take data from it i.e. the textLabel for example?